# Tcl: Difference between different ways of adding instance class

Tags: tcl

I found two ways to instance class:

one is:

```
class_name create instance
instance class_method
```

the other is:

```
set instance [class_name new]
$instance class_method
```

Each way worked well, so is there any difference between two ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***only difference*** is that the `new` method on classes generates a unique name for you, and with the `create` method you get to specify what the name is. Both are provided because there's use cases for each of them. Use whichever makes sense for you. (Note that class objects themselves are always named because of how they're generally used, and so you can't normally create classes with `new`; it's hidden on `oo::class` instances.)

For the sake of completeness only, there's an additional way to make instances, `createWithNamespace`, which lets you also specify the name of the state namespace of the object. It's not exposed by default (you have to manually `export` it for general use) and is pretty specialist for people who aren't doing deep shenanigans. You probably don't want to use it.

At some point in the future `new` may be enhanced so that it also enables garbage collection for the object, whereas `create` will not (because you know the name out-of-band). Specifically, I've written a TIP for doing this for Tcl 9.0 but I don't have a working implementation yet, so do not hold your breath.

Comment: Got it. In tclsh, `class_name create foo` will return `::foo`,`Error`,`Error`,`Error` and `set foo [class_name new]` will return `::oo::Obj50`,`::oo::Obj51`,`::oo::Obj52`,`::oo::Obj53`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some cases,

class defined as this:

```
oo::class create class_name {
    variable text
    method add {t} { set text $t }
    method print { } { puts $text }
}
```

First way:

```
class_name create foo
foo add "abc"
foo print

class_name create foo
```

It will return:

```
abc
Error: can't create object "foo": command already exists with that name
```

Second way:

```
set foo [class_name new]
$foo add "abc"
$foo print

set foo [class_name new]
$foo add "def"
$foo print
```

It will return:

```
abc
def
```

This is one difference I found, and it seems like **secnod way** is more convenient.

Still expecting master to provide authoritative answers or documents.

Comment: I wouldn't see the second one as more convenient IMHO. I see the first one as more convenient because it knows and tells me I'm probably doing something wrong since I'm trying to overwrite an instance I created earlier, which can cause issues more often than not, after all, if I need a new instance, it's most likely that it's different from a previous one, thus it will most likely be named differently.

Comment: @Jerry  Yeah, you're right, but there is some other situation. For example, the variable i as the loop iterator, which I don't care so much and will be overwritten again and again (this is much more like my usage). So the best way may be to detect whether the class instance exist or not, then destroy it and output a message. I'm still finding how to detect the class instance existence, do you have any idea?